# How to grep csv documents to APPEND info and keep the old data intact?

Tags: excel, grep, emeditor

I have huge_database.csv like this:

name,phone,email,check_result,favourite_fruit

```
sam,64654664,sam@example.com,,

sam2,64654664,sam2@example.com,,

sam3,64654664,sam3@example.com,,

[...]
```

===============================================

then I have 3 email lists:

- good_emails.txt
- bad_emails.txt
- likes_banana.txt

### the contents of which are:

good_emails.txt:

```
sam@example.com

sam3@example.com
```

---

bad_emails.txt:

```
sam2@example.com
```

---

likes_banana.txt:

```
sam@example.com

sam2@example.com
```

===============================================

I want to do some grep, so that at the end the output will be like this:

```
sam,64654664,sam@example.com,y,banana

sam2,64654664,sam2@example.com,n,banana

sam3,64654664,sam3@example.com,y,
```

- I don't mind doing it in multiple steps manually and, perhaps, in some complex algorithm such as copy pasting to multple files. What matters to me is the reliability, and most importantly the ability to process very LARGE csv files with more than 1M lines.
- What must also be noted is the lists that I will "grep" to add data to some of the columns will most of the times affect at most 20% of the total csv file rows, meaning the remaining 80% must be intact and if possible not even displace from their current order.
- I would also like to note that I will be using a software called EmEditor rather than spreadsheet softwares like Excel due to the speed of it and the fact that Excel simply cannot process large csv files.

How can this be done?

Will appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Googling, trial and error, grabbing my head from frustration.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Filter all good emails with Filter. Open [Advanced Filter](https://www.emeditor.org/en/cmd_search_filterbar_advanced.html). Next to the Add button is Add Linked File. Add the `good_emails.txt` file, set to the email column, and click Filter. Now only records with good emails are shown.

[image]

Select column 4 and type `y`. Now do the same for bad emails and change the column to `n`. Follow the same steps and change the last column values to the correct string.